# Validação HTML der mascara Jquery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, mvc, razor

Pessoal tenho uma tela em ASP.NET MVC usando Razor, que no edit retorno dados que ja foram salvos para edição.
Num dos meus campos é do tipo (decimal) uso para salvar valor monetário. Este campo quando vou dar o post para executar a edição no controller para no HTML nem indo ao controller retornando os eguinte menssagem.

The field Cost must be a number.

Obvio que el diz que é uma string(devido a mascara) e não um numero decimal como o tipo do model.
Ai o que acho estranho que uso o mesmo código html na view de novo CREATE e não paro nesta validação.

Alguém tem algum id~eia do que pode estra ocorrendo?

Segue o código:

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modalform")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.moneymask.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">R$</span>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus", required = "required"}})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Cost, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <br/>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-11" style="text-align: left">
                        <input type="submit" value="SALVAR" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Descobri o problema era neste script render:

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

Após retira-lo deu tudo certo.